# Android Studio SQLite Column Sum

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum

I have a table with several columns and I'm looking to create a function that will return the sum of all the entries in a particular column.

For debug purposes, I've simply set the return string to "1" to confirm the rest of my code works properly, which it does.

Can anyone help me with the necessary code to sum the column and return the value?

```
public String TotalServings(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    //From the table "TABLE_PRODUCTS" I want to sum all the entries in the column "COLUMN_SERVINGS"

    String Servings = "1";
    return Servings;
}
```

Comment: `SELECT SUM(COLUMN_SERVINGS) FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS` ???

Comment: Is this your homework jaja?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
//This method returns an int, if u need it string parse it
public Int TotalServings(){
                int serving =0;
                SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                        "SELECT SUM(COLUMN_SERVINGS) FROM TABLE_PRODUCTS", null);
                    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        serving = cursor.getInt(0);
                    }

                return serving;
            }
```